# NSInternalInconsistencyException error registering own cell (ios, swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I try to use my own cell in a taleview and I get the following error. I checked various samples (also in stackoverflow) and even did not manage to get it running. Can someone see what I am doing wrong ?

Error:

```
2015-05-10 07:55:53.145 Prototypes[915:19191] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FE514C52-DD27-4114-A51F-2A837A6E9CF2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9AA69B81-4001-4E95-8DD8-2D0B742B175A/Prototypes.app> (loaded)' with name 'ResultsCell''
```

Code:
UIViewController:
var searchResults: UITableView  =   UITableView();

class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate/*, UITableViewDataSource*/ {
    var arrayResults: [(EventID: Int, sTitle: String)] = [];

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let data = (EventID: 0, sTitle: "MyEvent 0");
        arrayResults.append(data);

        let fSearchResultY:CGFloat=fButtonHeight+fButtonY;
        searchResults.frame = CGRectMake(0, fSearchResultY, screenwidth, screenheight-fSearchResultY);

        searchResults.delegate      =   self;
        searchResults.dataSource    =   self;

        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "ResultsCell", bundle:nil)
        searchResults.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        self.view.addSubview(searchResults);
}
```

UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cellImage: UIImageView
    var cellTitle: UILabel
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        cellImage=UIImageView();
        cellTitle=UILabel();
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

UPDATE after suggestions:

I replaced

```
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "ResultsCell", bundle:nil)
    searchResults.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

"Cell")
with

```
searchResults.registerClass(ResultsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell");
```

But then I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle' with name 'ResultsCell''
Code: UIViewController: var searchResults: UITableView = UITableView();` means that iOS can't find the NIB/XIB with name `ResultsCell` in your bundle. Make sure that you have that XIB file or if you want to create table view cell by code, you should use `-[UITableView registerClass: forCellReuseIdentifier:]` instead

Comment: I created the ResultsCell Class using the wizard in XCode : Cocoa Touch Class. I have no XIB File. I have only .swift files. I can't imagine, that I have to do any files by myself ?

Comment: I used now :  searchResults.registerClass(ResultsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell");   
But now I get the Error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Your reuse identifier doesn't match. `Cell` vs `cell`

Comment: That was it in the end. Thanks a lot !